# awk extract columns that meet condition

Tags: awk, scripting, csv

I'm writing a script to prepare a csv file that takes columns number 5, 6, 7, 8, 10 and 13; takes the rows that on column 44 are equal to 7 and also meet that the rows that on column 3 are equal to 1, at the same time.

Input:

```
"ID_Bcn_2019","ID_Bcn_2016","Codi_Principal_Activitat","Nom_Principal_Activitat","Codi_Sector_Activitat","Nom_Sector_Activitat","Codi_Grup_Activitat","Nom_Grup_Activitat","Codi_Activitat_2019","Nom_Activitat","Codi_Activitat_2016","Nom_Local","SN_Oci_Nocturn","SN_Coworking","SN_Servei_Degustacio","SN_Obert24h","SN_Mixtura","SN_Carrer","SN_Mercat","Nom_Mercat","SN_Galeria","Nom_Galeria","SN_CComercial","Nom_CComercial","SN_Eix","Nom_Eix","X_UTM_ETRS89","Y_UTM_ETRS89","Latitud","Longitud","Direccio_Unica","Codi_Via","Nom_Via","Planta","Porta","Num_Policia_Inicial","Lletra_Inicial","Num_Policia_Final","Lletra_Final","Solar","Codi_Parcela","Codi_Illa","Seccio_Censal","Codi_Barri","Nom_Barri","Codi_Districte","Nom_Districte","Referencia_cadastral","Data_Revisio"
1059038,"68849","1","Actiu","2","Serveis","14","Restaurants, bars i hotels (Inclòs hostals, pensions i fondes)","1400002","Restaurants","1400002","QUATRE COSES","1","1","1","1","1","0","1","","1","","1","","0","Rambla Catalunya","430088.542","4582365.352","41.38978196","2.16378361","089004, 329-329, LOC 10","089004","CONSELL DE CENT","LOC","10","329","","329","","114142","019","60490","079","07","la Dreta de l'Eixample","02","Eixample","0125419DF3802E","20190509"
1075454,"","1","Actiu","2","Serveis","16","Altres","1600400","Serveis a les empreses i oficines","16004","SORIGUE","1","1","1","1","1","0","1","","1","","1","","1","","427229.272","4577543.637","41.34610100","2.13016600","222206, 19-19, LOC 10","222206","MOTORS","LOC","10","19","","19","","","","","025","12","la Marina del Prat Vermell","03","Sants-Montjuïc","","20190925"
1075453,"","1","Actiu","2","Serveis","16","Altres","1600102","Activitats emmagatzematge","1600102","CEJIDOS SIVILA S.A","1","1","1","1","1","0","1","","1","","1","","1","","427178.393","4577526.160","41.34593900","2.12956000","222206, 278-282, LOC 10","222206","MOTORS","LOC","10","278","","282","","","","","025","12","la Marina del Prat Vermell","03","Sants-Montjuïc","","20190925"
```

Output:

```
"Codi_Sector_Activitat","Nom_Sector_Activitat","Codi_Grup_Activitat","Nom_Grup_Activitat","Nom_Activitat","SN_Oci_Nocturn"
"2","Serveis","14","Restaurants, bars i hotels (Inclòs hostals, pensions i fondes)","Restaurants","1"
```

For the moment, in my script I've got:

```
#!/bin/awk -f

BEGIN { FS = OFS = "," }

NR == 1 { print $5, $6, $7, $8, $10, $13 }

NR != 1 {
         if ($44 == 7) {print}
         if ($3 == 1) {print}
}
```

But I'm not sure about the last part. So my question would be, how do I extract only the rows that meet these conditions: `($44 == 7)`and `($3 == 1)` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A starting note: none of 44 field cells equals 7. You have `07`.

This is not awk, it's [Miller](https://github.com/johnkerl/miller), I think it could be useful

```
mlr --csv  -N filter -S '$3=="1" && $44=="07" || $1=~"ID"' then cut -f 5,6,7,8,10,13  input.csv >outuput.csv
```

Some comments:

- `filter` to filter using you conditions and to have in output the heading row;
- `cut` to extract the fields you want

In output you will have

| Codi_Sector_Activitat | Nom_Sector_Activitat | Codi_Grup_Activitat | Nom_Grup_Activitat | Nom_Activitat | SN_Oci_Nocturn |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | Serveis | 14 | Restaurants, bars i hotels (Inclòs hostals, pensions i fondes) | Restaurants | 1 |

Comment: Works really well, thanks! How would I put that into a miller file?

Comment: @LlemColop I have edit my answer :) If it works for you, please accept my answer as the right one

Comment: Accepted! But I was referring to saving the code on a miller script if such thing exists.

Comment: @LlemColop You can use simply a bash script

Answer (score 3):

You can roll all the conditions into one pattern rule - note however that since your CSV fields are all quoted, you need to account for that in the pattern ex.

```
$ cat prepare.awk
#!/bin/awk -f

BEGIN { FS = OFS = "," }

NR == 1 || $44 == "\"7\"" || $3 == "\"1\"" {
  print $5, $6, $7, $8, $10, $13
}
```

Then

```
$ ./prepare.awk Input
"Codi_Sector_Activitat","Nom_Sector_Activitat","Codi_Grup_Activitat","Nom_Grup_Activitat","Nom_Activitat","SN_Oci_Nocturn"
"2","Serveis","14","Restaurants, pensions i fondes)","1400002"
"2","Serveis","16","Altres","Serveis a les empreses i oficines","1"
"2","Serveis","16","Altres","Activitats emmagatzematge","1"
```

Note that all of the non-header rows in your sample Input have `"1"` in the 3rd column.

If you want to select rows where **both** non-header conditions match, change the condition to

```
NR == 1 || ( $44 == "\"7\"" && $3 == "\"1\"" )
```